# Is there much to be gained by have a column which might hold up to ten characters as a VARCHAR?

Tags: sql-server

I have a simple Id column in my database. It can contain information like U001-01 or perhaps something a little more later on.

I am thinking it will be about ten characters and I would like to have an index on this column.

Is there really much to be gained by having this as a VARCHAR(10) instead of a CHAR(10). Note that already my rows will be over 1000 bytes long.

Comment: CHAR uses static typing so is more efficient than VARCHAR which uses dynamic typing.

Comment: @rontornambe: Can you elaborate on that? Do you really mean "typing" or "storage allocation"?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This was an unfinished comment as the answer below stipulates and replaces "typing" with allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would recommend using `varchar()` instead of `char()`, unless you really want your values padded with spaces at the end.  Spaces can make it cumbersome to combine the field with other fields using concatenation.  It can also get confusing to remember whether and when the extra spaces matter for comparison purposes.

The additional two bytes of overhead is usually insignificant.  After all, if your average value length is less than 8 (`n` - 2), then the overall storage is still less with a `varchar()` versus `char()` representation.

In general, I default to `varchar()`.  If I know a coding is fixed length (US state codes, ISO country codes, 9-digit US zip codes, social security numbers), then I will consider a `char()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The index is effective if it is VARCHAR(10) or a CHAR(10)

Not a lot to save on 10 from a size perspective
Varchar has 2 bytes of overhead
Char reserves space so changing or later inserting the value will not cause page splits (fragmentation)
The page split takes time and fragmentation slows performance of the table
I typically use char for 40 and under just to avoid page splits

[char and varchar (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

> If you use char or varchar, we recommend the following:

- Use char when the sizes of the column data entries are consistent.
- Use varchar when the sizes of the column data entries vary
  considerably.
- Use varchar(max) when the sizes of the column data entries vary
  considerably, and the size might exceed 8,000 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

As my unfinished comment suggests, CHAR uses static type allocation so is more efficient than VARCHAR which uses dynamic type allocation. CHAR columns are space padded, so this must be considered when performing comparisons.

Comment: No you do not have to consider the padding when performing comparison.  Talling spaces are not considered.  Char(10) 'Cat' = Varchar(40) 'Cat'

Comment: That depends on the DBMS and the type of comparison. Here's an Oracle example (I think DB2 also includes spaces in some comparisons): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a77db/1

Comment: The question is tagged sql-server